# Send packets larger than 64K in TCP

Tags: networking, packet, tcp

As far as we know the absolute limitation on TCP packet size is 64K (65535 bytes), and in practicality this is far larger than the size of any packet you will see, because the lower layers (e.g. ethernet) have lower packet sizes. The MTU (Maximum Transmission Unit) for Ethernet, for instance, is 1500 bytes.

I want to know, Is there any any way or any tools, to send packets larger than  64k?

I want to test a device in facing with packet larger than 64k! I mean I want to see, if I send a packet larger than 64K, how it behave? Does it drop some part of it? Or something else.

So :

1- How to send this large packets? What is the proper layer for this?

2- How the receiver behave usually?

Comment: test `SO_SNDBUF`  socket option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as a TCP packet. TCP data is sent and received in *segments,* which can be as large as you like up to the limits of the API you're using, as they can be comprised of multiple IP packets. At the receiver TCP is indistinguishable from a byte stream.

NB [osi](/questions/tagged/osi) has nothing to do with this, or anything else.

Answer (score 4):

The IP packet format has only 16 bit for the size of the packet, so you will not be able to create a  packet with a size larger than 64k. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Total_Length. Since TCP uses IP as the lower layer this limit applies here too.

Comment: Isn't there any any way or device to send packets larger than this? I mean isn't there any way to create a packet by ataching some bytes together and make a for example 65K packet and send it in a row? Does the network Card (NIC) split data to packets or the application sending packets?

Comment: The "physical" network packets are even smaller than the "logical" IP packets, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumbo_frame so you have restrictions on multiple levels which are inherent to the packet format and which are not just a software enforced limit.

Answer (score 0):

TCP segments are not size-limited. The thing which imposes the limit is that IPv4 and IPv6 packets have 16 bit length fields, so a size larger than this limit is not possible to express.

However, [RFC 2675](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2675) is a proposed standards for IPv6 which would expand the length field to 32 bits, allowing much larger TCP segments.

See [here](https://netdevconf.info/0x15/session.html?BIG-TCP) for a talk about why this change could help improve performance and [here](https://lwn.net/ml/netdev/20220203015140.3022854-1-eric.dumazet@gmail.com/) for a set of (experimental) patches to Linux to enable this RFC.